# Debug/Start disabled in VS2017 on .NET Core projects

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I was try using .NET Core examples with Visual Studio 2017 (1.5.8), all as Admin on Windows 10.

I can't run or debug any .NET Core project, the menu is always disabled and if I hit 'Start'/'Run' it yells to set an already activated start project!

[image: Error on click 'Run' (Sorry, in german)]

I think all required libraries are installed:

[image: Workload]

After generating any project from templates of console app (.NET Core), class library (.NET Core) or ASP.NET Core, Ctrl-F5/F5 are disabled.

If I use 'Windows Desktop'-console app, debugging/run is allowed.

[image: Disabled Ctrl-F5/F5]

Thanks in advance for any suggestion to solve this issue.

PS: Previously this was a Docker related title, but it seems to be a .NET Core Problem.

Comment: Uninstalling web development workload and reinstalling might help.

Comment: Is `dotnet` available from your command line?

Comment: Right! It's is and build/run is available over CLI

Answer (score 1):

in addition to the tipp from [t-prisar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3925626/t-prisar), I clean up my VS installation (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/visualstudio/install/troubleshooting-installation-issues?view=vs-2017)), restart the PC, download and install a new VS2017 Community Edition from [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/de/downloads/) and reinstall the Workload (more than 4 GB).

Now I'm able to run the example .NET Core console application. The 'Run'/'Debug' (Ctrl-F5/F5) is already available. Yipeee....

Thanks a lot, the simplest ideas are most the best.... doesn't see the wood for the trees ;-)